Read specific column of excel file in R, but using name instead of range/placement, like `col_select` argument in `readr::read_csv`
I have a multiple excel files being received from multiple users.  I am using readxl package in R to read the files.
But my requirement is a bit different.  Suppose I want to import only a few columns from the table (in excel sheet) which may be placed in different ranges in different workbooks.  But I know the column names in these files, which I want to import are same.  So How can I import those specific columns.
Example, If I want to import column named "Species" from this file while not being aware of its position in sheet.
read_excel(readxl_example("datasets.xls"))

To clarify further, I want that column names may be provided in a character vector exactly like col_select argument in readr::read_csv() function does.

Assuming you know all existing columns ahead of time, and your sole intent is to not read in the data first, you can use col_types=c("skip",...,"text").
If you know the existing names (and order), then you can skip this first step, otherwise ...
row1 <- read_excel(readxl_example("datasets.xls"), n_max = 1)
existing_columns <- colnames(row1)
existing_columns
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     

Knowing the existing names, we can skip/select what need:
col_types <- replace(rep("skip", length(existing_columns)), 
                     existing_columns %in% "Species", "guess")
col_types
# [1] "skip"  "skip"  "skip"  "skip"  "guess"
read_excel(readxl_example("datasets.xls"), col_types=col_types)
# # A tibble: 150 × 1
#    Species
#    <chr>  
#  1 setosa 
#  2 setosa 
#  3 setosa 
#  4 setosa 
#  5 setosa 
#  6 setosa 
#  7 setosa 
#  8 setosa 
#  9 setosa 
# 10 setosa 
# # ℹ 140 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


This method I also thought of.  But actually I have multiple Excel files from multiple users.  So what they are doing is putting column in their own ways.  I want only a few columns from all of the Excel files and then merge them in a single data.frame.  again the second part I can manage through purrr, but still I thought that there is a method to get specific columns without reading any rows beforehand

@AnilGoyal Do all files (workbooks) have a single tab, the same tab, or the column can be in different tabs?

Yes, all files having sheet 2, in this case

Until it's directly supported in readr, I don't know of any way to pull specific columns by-name from an .xls file. If they were .xlsx, though, you could do openxlsx2::read_xlsx("file.xlsx", cols="Species"), I think.

@r2evans, this package is also taking the cols argument values in similar fashion to that of readxl

Okay, I think I misread it, sorry about that. I don't know of any package that does what you're asking for. Is there a performance penalty you're trying to avoid, or is it mostly elegant avoidance of double-read that is distasteful?

@r2evans yeah you got it.  Distateful it is.  Otherwise I knew that method
